# Can eck operator be used to upgrade elasticsearch from 7.8.1 to 7.17.9 with a rolling upgrade strategy?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone please point me how to use eck operator to upgrade elasticsearch from 7.8.1 to 7.17.9 with a rolling upgrade strategy?
I have already gone through:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-upgrade-deployment.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/rolling-upgrades.html

but there are no examples for the same. I have an old installation so I don't have much details about the same.
It would be great if someone can provide some example for the process to be following and if rolling upgrade is even possible.